# How to load a sf::Image from an array of pixels in SFML?

Tags: c++, sfml

I would like to load an image in sfml from a 2d array containing 3 values for each pixel (RGB). The array would look something like this:

```
{
 {{255, 255, 255}, {255, 255, 255}},
 {{255, 255, 255}, {255, 255, 255}}
}
```

The array above describes a 2x2 image which is white. How can I turn this into an Image in sfml (`sf::Image`)?

Comment: Did you check with the [manual](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Image.php)?

Comment: I suggest that you [take a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18811488/5844572), I think you'll like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create an `sf::Image` object from a pixel array, then you are interested in the [`sf::Image::create()`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Image.php#a1c2b960ea12bdbb29e80934ce5268ebf) member function overload that takes a `const Uint8 *`:

```
void sf::Image::create(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, const Uint8 * pixels);
```

As the name suggests, the last parameter, `pixels`, corresponds to the array of pixels you want to create the `sf::Image` from. Note that this pixel array is assumed to be in the [*RGBA* format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_model) (this contrasts with the *RGB* format suggested in the code of the question). That is, the array must hold **four `Uint8`s for *each pixel*** – i.e., a `Uint8` for each component: *red*, *green*, *blue* and *alpha*.

---

As example, consider the following pixel array, `pixels`, made up of *six* pixels:

```
const unsigned numPixels = 6;
sf::Uint8 pixels[4 * numPixels] = {
    0,   0,   0,   255, // black
    255, 0,   0,   255, // red
    0,   255, 0,   255, // green
    0,   0,   255, 255, // blue
    255, 255, 255, 255, // white
    128, 128, 128, 255, // gray
};
```

Then, we can create an `sf::Image` object from the `pixels` array of pixels:

```
sf::Image image;
image.create(3, 2, pixels);
```

The pixels of the `sf::Image` created above will correspond to these:

[image: 3x2 image]

This is a *3x2*-pixel image, However, flipping the image's *width* and *height* arguments passed to the `sf::Image::create()` as done in:

```
sf::Image image;
image.create(2, 3, pixels);
```

This results in a *2x3*-pixel image instead:

[image: 3x3 image]

Note, however, that both `sf::Image` objects above are created from the same array of pixels, `pixels`, and they both are made up of *six* pixels – the pixels are just arranged differently because the images have different dimensions. Nevertheless, the pixels are the same: a black, a red, a green, a blue, a white and a gray pixel.